# is there a replacement word for "previous of previous"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adjectives

I want to describe a situation that happened two levels earlier. 
I use the *bash* shell to navigate through directories.

Say I started at the directory `/home`, and then I moved to the directory `/home/Downloads`, and finally I moved to `/home/Videos`.

Now I'll describe how to navigate to earlier directories:

To go to the previous directory type `cd -`.
And to go to the **previous of previous** directory type `cd --`

As you notice, **previous of previous** sounds odd.

Is there a replacement word for "previous of previous"?
Or how would you paraphrase it to make it sound grammatical?

Comment: To go to the previous directory type `cd -`. And to go to the directory before,  type cd --

Comment: @TusharRaj Thank you for responding. Your suggestion looks neat but I want kind of math way to emphasize its ordinality.

Comment: Parent and grandparent?

Comment: @kenn: Ordinality? Sorry man, but we don't speak math. The closest English could get you would be 'grandprevious'. Try [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) or [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @deadrat: Jinx.

Comment: It just means that one of us is very, very clever.  Maybe both.

Comment: @TusharRaj `grandprevious` also sounds unfamiliar. You can be more creative :) you are getting closer.

Comment: Like @deadrat said, parent directory is pretty standard among techies, and grandparent is often used to extend the metaphor/terminology. 'Grandprevious' was just a neologism of mine.

Comment: @deadrat: Let's go with both!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/word-meaning-two-paragraphs-previous

Comment: @hatchet
I did a quick search on the net prior to asking question here. I read that topic too but it doesn't provide a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Did I just learn a bash shell tip from English SE?  :-|

Comment: @deadrat It's not actually the parent directory. Per the Bash documentation, "cd -" will take you to "The previous working directory", not the parent directory.

Comment: What you have is a "directory history" and you are moving back one or two positions in the history.  Do not try to say previous of previous it's very confusing (some folks suspect it means "grandparent" - see the comments above).

Comment: @recognizer Doh!

Comment: @deadrat I assumed the same thing when I read the question. Then I realized I had best check the actual details.

Comment: @recognizer
Thank you for the tip. When I posted my question I didn't think of people would confuse it with directory path definition such as parent of current directory or parent of the directory before. As you clarified it's related to  `directory history` in the bash shell.

Comment: @kenn hey just to ping you with this whenever you are next on, it turns out that someone pointed out in a comment to my answer that `bash` cannot navigate to  the antipenultimate directory, which was news to me but it's 100% correct.

Comment: @CRDrost You are right about that. I don't know how I acquired that misconception, I used to use some `bash` functions to navigate between directories, I might think that `cd --` take you to `antepenaltimate` directory, but it's wrong for `bash` environment. `cd --` takes you to `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 13):

**antepenultimate** - Two before the last. Penultimate is just before the last. Before the penultimate is antepenultimate.

Some shells will allow you to use the up arrow to recall the last command, so I call antepenultimate, up-up-up.

Comment: You appear to get my point but your approach is rather fantastic.

Comment: correct answer here

Comment: I was just thinking *anteprior* should be a word.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: there used to be a preantepenultimate meaning third before last.

Answer (score 10):

*penultimate* or *next-to-last* or *second-to-last*.

Ultimate means last, penultimate means next-to-last.

That can refer to latest instead of last, but I guess that is what you are after here, since your example seems to suggest chronological access.

*Last* can mean many things, but *next-to-last* always refers to, well, the thing that is prior to the last one, however *last* is meant.  IOW, whatever ordering is used to define *last*, the same ordering handles *next-to-last* correctly.

(If you mean only moving **up** the directory hierarchy, then *parent* and *grandparent* are appropriate.)

Comment: Drew, the word I was trying to bring up was `next-to-last` It sounds well. But what about the third, the fourth level directories? How would you define them?

Comment: Neither of the suggestions here works in the context given. Both the paenultimate and the next-to-last directory would be one that appears just before the very last directory in a directory listing. It doesn’t work for a directory that is two steps back through your browsing history.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet
I'd like to see your answer too.

Comment: @kenn pointing out that an answer is incorrect does not imply that one can think of a correct answer.  This is especially true if there *is* no correct answer, which I am inclined to think is the case here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't believe _next-to-last_ carries a universal context; if the task is moving backwards through history, _next-to-last_ accurately describes _the place I was before the last place I was before now_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: *Next-to-last* is relative to *last* - it depends for its meaning on the meaning of *last*, which is what I said, explicitly. *Last* can refer to lots of different things, one of which is the last in a fixed, ordered set, such as a complete directory listing (that's your interpretation, though there is nothing about a directory listing in the question or the answer given here). It can refer also to the latest directory accessed; or created; or modified;...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: ... It can refer to the last directory component shown in a given path (absolute directory name). That's the case for the OP, and it is the interpretation I was referring to: In /foo/bar/toto/titi/, titi is the last directory component, and toto is the next-to-last one. Their absolute directory names (paths) are /foo/bar/toto/titi and /foo/bar/toto/, respectively.

Comment: In addition to what @JanusBahsJacquet has said: "parent" and "grandparent" are *definitely not* what you want, because in this context they already have very specific meanings - the parent of `/home/Videos` is `/home`, and its grandparent is `/`.

Comment: @psmears: If the OP is only talking about moving up the directory hierarchy, then *parent* and *grandparent* are exactly the terms used. If the OP instead means chronological access (which I think might be the case) then *last* and *next-to-last* (or *penultimate*) are the terms used. It all depends on what notion of *last* is involved.

Comment: @Drew: From the question it's very clear that chronological access is intended - look at the example directories given - so *parent/grandparent* are definitely out!

Comment: @psmears: The OP is not so clear, IMO, but I've clarified my answer, hopefully. *Parent* and *grandparent* apply to directory hierarchy (only). And I agree that the OP seems to refer to chronological access (but I disagree that the is "*very clear*" from the question as posed).

Comment: @kenn: I don't know a good term for the 3rd and 4th. You could say *third to last* or *next to next to last* for the 3rd, etc., but that's about it, I think.

Comment: @Drew: Given that it's talking about the operation of the `cd -` and `cd --` commands, it's a very safe assumption that the intent is chronological. I guess if you're not familiar with the operation of those commands it may be less clear, but I think the example still shows what's going on... in any case, thanks for clarifying your answer :)

Comment: @psmears: Yes, that's true. Which means that all of that part of the OP is unclear - for this site. As a question about English, the question as posed is unclear wrt what is meant by *last* etc. This is not a site where people are expected to know what `cd ..` or `cd -` might mean, and in which shell, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You may need something like *the one before last*:

> Do X to go to the last [or *previous*] directory; do Y to go to **the one before last**.

Here's an example:

> The two last chapters, which were not covered in the course proper, are perhaps less easily accessible: the **one before last** because it is rather technical, the last one because it requires some (elementary) knowledge of analytic (or algebraic) complex geometry.

([*Complex Tori and Abelian Varieties*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KpMwNHhrj9IC&pg=PR7&dq=%22one+before+last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i7meVfizGIqmNviflPgK&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22one%20before%20last%22&f=false), p. vii; emphasis added)

Comment: I don't think I can use it in my  case, because the ultimate directory is not known.

Comment: Instead of _last_, just use _that_: “Do X to go to the previous directory; do Y to go to the one before that”. Or alternatively, “Do X to go back one step; do Y to go back two steps”.

Comment: @kenn It's used for chronological or logical sequence: the *current* directory is the one you're in right now; the *last* is the one you were in before now; the *one before last* is the one you were in before that.

Comment: @MattGutting this use of "last" is ambiguous and can be confusing.  If you are at the 8th station of a transit line having 10 stations, and you just arrived from the 7th station, the phrase "last station" could denote the 7th station or the 10th.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just say *previous but one* (or *previous bar one*)?

I find it self-explanatory (in analogy to *last but one*). Google gives me quite a lot of hits in exactly the requested sense. Example:

> The core principle of renku is “link and shift”. “Link” signifies that each verse links somehow to its predecessor and “shift”, by contrast, means that each new verse must shift away from the **previous-but-one verse**, and have nothing in common with it. Thus, in any three consecutive verses A, B and C: B is to link to A and C links to B, but crucially C shifts right away from A.

([HAIKU SPIRIT: Guidelines to compose a renku](http://www.haikuspirit.org/renkuEN2.html), emphasis mine)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any commonly used terminology, but to specify this with ordinality you could use **first antecedent** (for cd -), **second** antecedent (cd --) and so on.

In the context of bash, you could perhaps go for **second last** *history entry* (cd --) etc, though since you seem to limit this to cd commands that is not quite right either. Second last *directory visited* perhaps?

Comment: Alok, your approach is smartly. It grammatically  sounds well.

Comment: @kenn unsolicited grammar advice: read up on copulative verbs (linking verbs).  In both of your sentences, the last word should be an adjective, not an adverb (smart, good).  Because of the nature of the verb, the word in that position describes the subject, not the verb.

Comment: @phoog thank you for correcting me. I ll never master English. By the way if you keep correcting my grammar errors you ll end up with proving `infinite set theory`

Comment: @kenn this is a mistake that many naive speakers make, generally not with *to be* but with others like *sounds, looks,* etc.  One sentence to illustrate: *A wet dog smells well, but a wet dog smells bad.*

Comment: I thank you all who posted an answer or commented on my topic. I should pick up one of the answers here. Alok's answer looks functional though it sounds a bit unfamiliar at first glance. Since nobody criticise his answer I ll accept it. But I had better wait a while.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't you be able to say, "the directory prior to the previous directory', etc.  I'm not sure if it's mathematically clear, but it would be very clear to me if I were the user who was trying to follow your instructions.

Comment: You are right in that context. It's possible to define it in a number of ways semantically. I wondered if there were any ordinal phrase I could replace `previous of previous`

Answer (score 3):

## *Before*, or *two before*

In fluent English you'd probably say, "Use `cd -` to go to the last directory, or `cd --` to get to **the one before that**." You can then refer to it inline as the "before-last" directory.

You should also consider describing them with reference to the present directory as the directory *before* and the directory *two before* the current one. If you need  to scale to larger numbers, you should definitely use this: it has the distinct advantage that you can refer to the directory fifty-eight before the current directory, and nobody has any ambiguity about what that means. The equivalent "previous-of-previous-of-previous-of..." will be unsustainable after 5 or 6 iterations.

Comment: Chris, I think you are a programmer and native English speaker. You presented a universal way to describe ordinality too. It's clear and precise.

Comment: @CR Drost: Not relevant to the OP's question but Chris are you sure `cd --` works as you said ?

Comment: @digital_infinity I mean it probably depends on what shell you're using but at least in Bash and Zsh it appears to do that:


`bash-3.2$ pwd`

`/Users/cdrost`

`bash-3.2$ cd /tmp`

`bash-3.2$ cd /var`

`bash-3.2$ cd --`

`bash-3.2$ pwd`

`/Users/cdrost`

Comment: @CR Drost. `--` means usually in gnu commands: "stop reading options, the following arguments are file names, not options". In your case there is zero following arguments so `cd --` is equal to `cd`. It is interpreted as "go the user's home directory".
See (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash/11382#11382) and (https://askubuntu.com/questions/711390/what-does-cd-do-i-used-it-and-im-now-stuck-in-a-directory)

Comment: @digital_infinity oh, now that is interesting. I thought bare `cd` didn't change your directory. You're right that my test was inadequate and they do in fact take us back to the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of previous use, "one level up", previous of previous use "two levels up". unless is going back in to navigation history, then this would not work.

Comment: Per the Bash documentation, "If directory is ‘-’, it is converted to $OLDPWD". OLDPWD is "The previous working directory as set by the cd builtin.". It's not the parent directory; it's the previous directory.

Comment: @recognizer
Yes, you are right about it. Thank you for clarification. Some posts such as `parent,  grandparent  directory` get meaningless. But montelof's approach is logical. He paraphrases the sentence.

Comment: in that case it could be history -1, History -2, History -3, etc. or just print the path as it would be. instead. like /home/Downloads, /home/Videos. and thats it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a programmer, but in any other context, I would probably use "former" and "latter".